# User defined function in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm new to JMeter. I want to create a user defined function and have to do verification in it. I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me for this..?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with other answers, you can also come up with our own function to make it appear in JMeter as shown below.

Check [here](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-extending-jmeter-creating-custom-functions/) for step by step tutorial for the implementation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to write the custom code in Java/Groovy/Javascript etc (chose from `Language` dropdown).

`Pre and Post processors, Assertions` also available for JSR223.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go for scripting-based [Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), i.e.

- [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion)
- [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion)

Both allow executing arbitrary code and conditionally set associated sampler success or failure. See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on using assertions for setting pass/fail criteria on JMeter samplers.